# Create a trigger that checks dates [problem]

Tags: mysql

I have a problem .. What is required is the creation of a trigger to check if the date of the destruction(dateEmpr) is less than the date of return(dateRetEff), it is increased 10 days to the date of the return

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE emprunter(
    numLivre VARCHAR(5),
    dateEmpr DATE,
    numInsc VARCHAR(5),
    dateRetEff DATE
);
```

This is my code .. and it tells me it's wrong

```
CREATE TRIGGER verifier_date 
BEFORE INSERT ON emprunter
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    if((SELECT DATEDIFF(NEW.dateRetEff, NEW.dateEmpr) from emprunter ) <0) then
        dateEmpr =  DATE_ADD(OLD.dateEmpr, INTERVAL 10 DAY);
    end if;
END;
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=  DATE_ADD(OLD.dateEmpr, INTERVAL 10 DAY)' at line 6

Comment: *`if((SELECT DATEDIFF(NEW.dateRetEff, NEW.dateEmpr) from emprunter ) <0) then ...`* - you cannot compare rowset and scalar value. *`... then dateEmpr = ...`* - `SET` operator lost. *`... DATE_ADD(OLD.dateEmpr, ...`* - `OLD.` not exists during INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER verifier_date 
    BEFORE INSERT ON emprunter
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        if NEW.dateRetEff < NEW.dateEmpr then
            SET NEW.dateEmpr =  NEW.dateEmpr + INTERVAL 10 DAY;
        end if;
    END;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f6111f99b83d8abf2db8541bc2094772)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: @Mohammed Code is correct. Link to the fiddle added - look and ensure. Maybe you forget about DELIMITER reassign?